# Angular UI grid :Show only selected objects

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-ui-grid

I have a code snippet

```
$scope.users = [
{ name: "abc", age: 10, location: 'Nagpur' },
{ name: "bcd", age: 30, location: 'Chennai' },
{ name: "efr", age: 29, location: 'Chennai' },
{ name: "abc", age: 25, location: 'Bangalore' },
{ name: "abc", age: 27, location: 'Vizag' }
];
$scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.users;
```

In grid how to show only users which have name = "abc"?

Comment: Check the below answer and mark it as accepted if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You just have to filter out all values from your array whose name is "abc"

```
angular.forEach($scope.users,function(val){
  if(val.name=='abc')
    $scope.abcUsers.push(val);
});

$scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.abcUsers;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.